# Not able to determine Font and style in a page

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a page but I am not able to determine it''s font style. I checked the view source but nothing is visible. Some lines are commented. Please let me know how to determine the font name:

```
<html>
<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/inner.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title></title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">


<!--
body {
 background-color: #ECECEC;
}
.style2 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style3 {
 font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 30px;
 color: #333333;
}
-->




</style>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- InstanceBeginRepeat name="RepeatRegion1" -->
<!-- InstanceBeginRepeatEntry -->
<div align="center">
  <!-- ImageReady Slices (Untitled-1) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="950" height="824" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="233" colspan="9"><img src="images/index_01.gif" width="950" height="233" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td height="57"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/index_02.gif" alt="" width="112" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="about_us.html"><img src="images/index_03.gif" alt="" width="87" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td colspan="2"><a href="out_work.html"><img src="images/index_04.gif" alt="" width="137" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="dissided_work.html"><img src="images/index_05.gif" alt="" width="161" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="news.html"><img src="images/index_06.gif" alt="" width="146" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="photo_gallary.html"><img src="images/index_07.gif" alt="" width="130" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="link.html"><img src="images/index_08.gif" alt="" width="104" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/index_09.gif" alt="" width="73" height="57" border="0"></a></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="images/index_10.gif" width="232" height="507"></td>
      <td height="307" colspan="6" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
<table width="716" height="493" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td height="493" colspan="2" valign="top"><table width="719" height="529" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="74"><img src="images/parichaya.gif" width="600" height="93"></td>
              </tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><table width="489" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2344;&#2366;&#2357;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;.&#2358;&#2358;&#2367;&#2325;&#2366;&#2306;&#2340; &#2332;&#2351;&#2357;&#2306;&#2340;&#2352;&#2366;&#2357; &#2358;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2375;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2357;&#2337;&#2367;&#2354;&#2366;&#2306;&#2330;&#2375; &#2344;&#2366;&#2357;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2325;&#2376;.&#2332;&#2351;&#2357;&#2306;&#2340;&#2352;&#2366;&#2357; &#2349;&#2366;&#2314;&#2360;&#2366;&#2361;&#2375;&#2348; &#2358;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2375;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td height="55"> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2310;&#2312;&#2330;&#2375; &#2344;&#2366;&#2357;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2350;&#2340;&#2368;. &#2325;&#2380;&#2358;&#2354;&#2381;&#2351;&#2366; &#2349;&#2366;&#2314;&#2360;&#2366;&#2361;&#2375;&#2348; &#2358;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2375;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2327;&#2366;&#2357;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2361;&#2369;&#2350;&#2327;&#2366;&#2357;, &#2340;&#2366;.&#2332;&#2366;&#2357;&#2354;&#2368;,&#2332;&#2367;.&#2360;&#2366;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366;. <br>
&#2348;&#2377;&#2350;&#2381;&#2348;&#2375; &#2354;&#2367;&#2306;&#2325; &#2325;&#2379;-&#2321;&#2346;.&#2361;&#2380;&#2360;&#2367;&#2306;&#2327; &#2360;&#2379;&#2360;&#2366;&#2351;&#2335;&#2368;,<br>
&#2410; &#2341;&#2366; &#2350;&#2332;&#2354;&#2366;, &#2360;&#2375;&#2325;&#2381;&#2335;&#2352; &#2344;&#2306;.&#2407;&#2413;,<br>
&#2357;&#2366;&#2358;&#2368;, &#2344;&#2357;&#2368;.&#2350;&#2369;&#2348;&#2306;&#2312; &#2410;&#2406;&#2406;&#2413;&#2406;&#2411;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2332;&#2344;&#2381;&#2350; </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2407;&#2415; &#2321;&#2325;&#2381;&#2335;&#2379;&#2348;&#2352; &#2407;&#2415;&#2412;&#2409;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2332;&#2344;&#2381;&#2350; &#2336;&#2367;&#2325;&#2366;&#2339;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2361;&#2369;&#2350;&#2327;&#2366;&#2357;, &#2340;&#2366;.&#2332;&#2366;&#2357;&#2354;&#2368;, &#2332;&#2367;.&#2360;&#2366;&#2340;&#2366;&#2352;&#2366;.</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2358;&#2367;&#2325;&#2381;&#2359;&#2339; </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2348;&#2368;.&#2325;&#2377;&#2350;.</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2344;&#2381;&#2351;&#2366;&#2340; &#2349;&#2366;&#2359;&#2366; </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2350;&#2352;&#2366;&#2336;&#2368;, &#2361;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2368; &#2357; &#2311;&#2306;&#2327;&#2381;&#2352;&#2332;&#2368;.</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2346;&#2340;&#2381;&#2344;&#2368;&#2330;&#2375; &#2344;&#2366;&#2357; </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2360;&#2380;.&#2340;&#2375;&#2332;&#2354; &#2358;&#2358;&#2367;&#2325;&#2366;&#2306;&#2340; &#2358;&#2367;&#2306;&#2342;&#2375;</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2309;&#2346;&#2340;&#2381;&#2351;&#2375; </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style3">&#2340;&#2375;&#2332;&#2360;, &#2360;&#2366;&#2361;&#2367;&#2354;.</td>
                  </tr>
<tr>
<td width="24"> </td>
                    <td width="173" valign="top" class="style3">&#2331;&#2306;&#2342;</td>
                    <td width="270" valign="top" class="style3">&#2358;&#2375;&#2340;&#2368;,&#2342;&#2369;&#2327;&#2381;&#2343;&#2346;&#2381;&#2352;&#2325;&#2381;&#2352;&#2367;&#2351;&#2366;.<br><br>
</td>
                  </tr>
</table></td>
              </tr>
</table></td>
          </tr></table>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="9" background="images/index_13.gif" height="103"> </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="112" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="87" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="104" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="161" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="146" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="130" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="104" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="73" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->

</div>
<!-- InstanceEndRepeatEntry -->
<!-- InstanceEndRepeat -->

</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->

</html>
```

Comment: styles are not under comments .. Check out my answer I have clarified it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles being applied are these two ..

```
body {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
}
.style3 {
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #333333;
}
```

so the font-family is over-written by "Arial Unicode MS" .. 
**Observe everywhere style3 is being assigned as class to all the `<td>` tags and style2 is not being used anywhere ..**

One thing you can do to get confirmed about my words .. Just delete `.style2` `.style3` and `body` styles in your code one by one and observe the changes in Browser ..

There are no lines commented .. To comment in CSS we use `/* Comment line here*/` 
(for a quick reference) Here is a [link for reference on comments](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rules_comments.htm)

Answer (score 1):

there is a style specified

```
.style2 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
```

So i think it may be verdana.

But style2 is not specified anywhere style3 is defined for the **td** class so it might be Arial.

Use Firefox Addon - **[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=firebug&cat=all&advancedsearch=1&as=1&appid=1&lver=3.5&atype=0&pp=20&pid=5&sort=&lup=)** it will shows style sheets, js and also html

Comment: Ah, you are right... of course, the HTML/XML style comment is not commenting the CSS inbetween, because we are inside a style section here, the only way to comment is using /* ... */

Comment: This was my immediate thought, but looking more closely .style2 is not assigned to any element, only .style3 as CapSoft noted. Any element without the .style3 class will be using the browser default font for text (if there were any!)

Answer (score 1):

the only text i see has style3
firebug will show it too you
it is 'Arial Unicode MS'

but why use .style3 in the css as selector when you can use:

```
table td{ 
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the Firebug plugin for Firefox.
Among other things it adds pect element" option to the contextmenu, so you can access all information by right-clicking an element.

If there is no font given via HTML and CSS, the displayed font will probably be your default browser/system font.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean programmatically via JavaScript, or using a browser tool?

Using a browser tool, the "**computed styles**" function in "**inspect elements**" in Firebug is a good bet, as the other answerers point out as well. It will give you something even if there was no font specified at all (in my case, "serif").

However, even the computed style gives you only the *specified* font-family and not the font *actually used*. As far as I know from my JavaScript attempts in that area, only IE returns those.

But I'm waiting for your reaction first before delving deeper into this - maybe the Firebug hint is already all you need.

Comment: No not programatically. Just using any tool. Actually the FONT Style code is commented there, then from where it is using FONT?

Comment: I think the syntax highlighting is misleading you, I don't think HTML comments apply in CSS. I get Arial Unicode when checking out your example. With Firebug, you can see thatg the definition comes from the commented out area.